# Binding issue - Value not updating on View

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

What i am trying to achieve is, when the check box is checked, the textbox will display True, when the checkbox is unchecked, text box will display False.

The issue at the moment is that initially it works, the box will be checked, and textbox will display true. But when i uncheck it, the text box remains saying True.

Sorry if i am missing something simple, still trying to grasp Wpf and c#.

Thanks for helping.

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
<CheckBox Content="Check me" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="88,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86"  IsChecked="{Binding CurrentValue, Mode= TwoWay}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentValue, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="88,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainView();
    }

}
```

MainView:

```
 public class MainView : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {  

    private bool currentValue = true;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool CurrentValue
    {
        get
        {
            return currentValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (currentValue == value)
            {
                return;
            }
                currentValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChange("Check_Value");

        }
    }



    protected void RaisePropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your property wrongly following how you  can  fix  this correctly

```
  public bool CurrentValue
    {
        get
        {
            return currentValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (currentValue != value)
            {    
              currentValue = value;
             RaisePropertyChange("CurrentValue");
            }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
RaisePropertyChange("Check_Value");
```

try

```
RaisePropertyChange("CurrentValue");
```

Value that pass must be the same as your property name

Comment: when you raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event property name that you pass must be exactly the same as the one in your view model that you want to be refreshed. It's also case sensitive so `CurrentValue` is not the same as for example `currentvalue`